Any selective media for corynebacterium acnes? What about isolation methods?
Looking for a media that is selective for Corynebacterium acnes or any isolation methods. Help is appreciated. Will be isolating from a bacterial consortia.

Welcome to the Biology Stack Exchange. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more information on this site and how it works. Please note the homework policy. I suggest you find a copy of Bergey's manual.
